# In shop page, I need to hide shop menu in header and footer woocommerce php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

I need to hide the shop and products in the header (shop page).

Comment: you mean to say only shop menu will be not shown on shop page the others will be there?

Comment: yes. only in shop page need to hide shop in header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class `shoppage` in menu link from admin panel. add below the code in `header.php`

[image]

```
     <?php
        if(is_shop()){

            echo "<style>.shoppage{display:none !important}</style>";

        }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = $(location).attr('href'),
    parts = url.split("/"),
    last_part = parts[parts.length-2];
if(last_part == 'shop')
{
    $('#menu-item-15').hide();
}
});

</script>
```

Add this into your theme's footer.php  and replace the `#menu-item-15` with your shop menu's id you can check the menu id with Firebug please  check image http://prntscr.com/flxk27

Comment: can't we use php to hide shop in header

Comment: yes but if jquery code i have answered is also correct you can use it header too

Comment: it ok enjoy programming